# What happens to my google account if I factory reset?

Tags: gmail, google-account, factory-reset

I've been using this Android phone for just over a year, but I'm worried about my Gmail and Google account which is connected to my phone. I want to change the email address on my Android because it's my main one.  If I lose my phone, someone can access my YouTube account which I've worked hard on.  They could also access my emails.

I'm worried if I do factory reset or the remove account, it will delete the account that it is connected to. Will it?

Answer (score 5):

No! Your google account is not stored locally on your device. It will still be available on any other device and on any other desktop browser you choose to use!